# simplifying algebraic expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From a textbook:
$km \times mn \times nk$

Answer says: $k^2m^2n^2$, but why can't that be simplified further to $(kmn)^2$?

$3pq^2r \times 6p^2qr \times 9pqr^2$

Answer says: $162p^4q^4r^4$, but why can't that be simplified further to $162(pqr)^4$?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Yes, km x mn x nk can be written as $(kmn)^2$.  Whether that is "simpler" than k^2m^2n^2 is a matter of taste.  Yes, $162p^4q^4r^4= 162(pqr)^4$.   In fact, it can be written as $2(3pqr)^4$.  Is that "simpler"?

Answer (score 0):

it is $$km\cdot mk\cdot nk=k\cdot k\cdot m\cdot m\cdot n\cdot n=k^2m^2n^2=(kmn)^2$$
and for your second question: $$3\cdot 6\cdot 9\cdot p\cdot p^2\cdot p\cdot q^2\cdot q\cdot q\cdot r\cdot r\cdot r^2=...$$?$$

Comment: The op knows the $k^2m^2n^2,$ and $162p^4q^4r^4$ representations.  The op is asking whether it is more simplified to represent, e.g., the first as $(kmn)^2$.  I.e.  Which form is "more simplified".  You're just repeating work the op has already done.